# Warning: count():

Tags: wordpress, warnings

Hey friends I am running my wordpress theme on `localhost` to make some changes. It shows following error without showing main navigation bar.

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\wamp64\www\fiverr\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 284 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003404144{main}( )...\index.php:0 20.0004404432require( 'C:\wamp64\www\fiverr\wp-blog-header.php' )...\index.php:17 30.908112387632require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\fiverr\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )...\wp-blog-header.php:19 40.925912455240include( 'C:\wamp64\www\fiverr\wp-content\themes\markut\page.php' )...\template-loader.php:74 50.925912455240get_header( )...\page.php:11 60.925912455616locate_template( )...\general-template.php:41 70.926112455712load_template( )...\template.php:647 80.926212456184require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\fiverr\wp-content\themes\markut\header.php' )...\template.php:688 90.927212470664wp_head( )...\header.php:15 100.927212470664do_action( )...\general-template.php:2614 110.927212471040WP_Hook->do_action( )...\plugin.php:453 120.927212471040WP_Hook->apply_filters( )...\class-wp-hook.php:310 131.027015883304markut_insert_fb_in_head( )...\class-wp-hook.php:286 141.027015899816the_excerpt( )...\index.php:158 151.027015899816get_the_excerpt( )...\post-template.php:362 161.027115899816apply_filters( )...\post-template.php:397 171.027115900216WP_Hook->apply_filters( )...\plugin.php:203 181.027115901960wp_trim_excerpt( )...\class-wp-hook.php:288 191.027115901960get_the_content( )...\formatting.php:3308 About UsWe'r a dynamic teamLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod"/>

The lines of post-template.php are:

```
if ( post_password_required( $post ) ) //281
return get_the_password_form( $post ); //282
if ( $page > count( $pages ) ) // if the requested page doesn't exist 284
$page = count( $pages ); // give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist 285
```

Comment: can you show us the code from post-template.php

Comment: Hey thanks for replying me... I could manage the error by editing the code. I wil provide the code to see someone.

Answer (score 1):

This bug related to WordPress core bug
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42814

Most often it occurs when you call the function `get_the_excerpt` or `get_the_content` outside the Loop provided that excerpt or content is empty.

So to fix it yourself you should find error place and check excerpt/content existing manually.

For example:

```
if(has_excerpt($post_id)) {
    $meta[] = sprintf('<meta name="description" content="%s">',
        get_the_excerpt($post_id)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused because you are using `$pages` wich is `null` because you are outside the main loop. This will cause php 7.2 to throw an error if attempting to count non-countable types.

You must wrap your code with the Wordpress main loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

        // your code

    }
}
```